# Value category of member enumerator

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) `a.m` is `prvalue` `the member of object expression, where m is a member enumerator or a non-static member function[2];`

Does it mean for object expression ie a.m where m is a member of a of enumeration type, the value category of expression itself would be prvalue?

As per my following testing, it does not seem to be the case. What did I miss?

```
enum class Color : char {
    Red = 'r'
};

struct Test {
    Color c;
};

void func(Color&&) {
    std::cout << "rvalue ref\n";
}

void func(Color&) {
    std::cout << "lvalue ref\n";
}

int main()
{
    Test t;
    func(t.c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`lvalue ref`

Comment: Member enumerator, sth like https://wandbox.org/permlink/keoe9gZa72UWWwe6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the 'enumerator' is the value of an enumeration not an object of the type of the enumeration:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

> An enumeration is a distinct type whose value is restricted to a range of values, which may include several explicitly named constants **("enumerators")**.

<sup>Slightly edited to remove fluff, bolding mine</sup>

So the standard is referring to when you access a class enumerator like:

```
struct Test {
   enum Colour {
     Red
   };
};

...

Test t;
t.Red; // <- This is a prvalue
```

[Here is a live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76330d859a339f69)

Comment: The non-static member function prvalue is actually about `obj.member_function_name`, which is unusable except to call it immediately afterwards, and exists only to simplify the standard (useless knowledge for any C++ programmer). https://wg21.link/expr.ref#6.3.2

Comment: @Artyer nice, i was a bit confused about this. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`t.c` in this case, is not a member enumerator, it's a member variable, of an `enum` type.

A member enumerator would be something like this:

```cpp
struct Test {
    enum Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE};
    Color c;
};

void func(Test::Color&&) {
    std::cout << "rvalue ref\n";
}

void func(Test::Color&) {
    std::cout << "lvalue ref\n";
}

int main()
{
    Test t;

    func(t.RED);
    return 0;
}
```

That will print `rvalue ref`. `t.RED` is a rvalue expression because it' not assignable, while `t.c` is not because you can assign a rvalue, like `t.RED` to it.